# Drupal sorting content type via relationship

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm new to drupal and everything just seems mind tangling. I've got two custom content types. First one is named "devices" - the parrent, and the second one is called "tasks", being the child. I've got a list of devices, and when I click on one and go to it's page, how can I create a custom "task" only for it? Thank you for any advice given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you'll be able to do out of the box. But the cool thing about Drupal is your not stuck in the box.

Checkout out: http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy

It has a drupal 7 dev version which probably works just fine.